# Slow Web Scraping For Loop - Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, web, scrape

I am trying to scrape the SEC's website to grab company headquarter data. The function is below and it just takes way too long to execute. Is there a better way of running it to make it faster and more efficient? Thanks so much!

```
def get_hq(cik):
    for i, row in Companies.iterrows():
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2810.1 Safari/537.36'}
        base_url = 'https://sec.report/CIK/{}'
        cik = Companies['CIK'][i]
        response_object = requests.get(base_url.format(cik), headers = headers)
        raw_html = html.fromstring(response_object.text)
        try:
            hq = raw_html.xpath('//tr[./td[contains(text(),"Business Address")]]/td[2]/text()')[0:]
            Companies['Headquarters'][i] = hq[0:]
        except:
            Companies['Headquarters'][i] = np.nan
```

Comment: Did you consider using Companies["CIK"].apply(get_hq) and moving the header and base_url outside the function?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't speed it up that much. Could this be an issue with my computing power or is it just the code? I am trying to run this for 4000 names

Comment: You should use apply function as it is quite faster than iterating over rows. I also think that it could be because there is the overhead of request being sent for each id and returned. If you think the response will not change for each of the ids, then offline it can be processed for once and then cached/pickled. Later can be read and processed. If the response change then you can simply run a script which runs 2 hours once to fetch the data and that can be cached and process everytime

Comment: For one, `iterrows()` is generally sluggish. This kind of problem will likely benefit from threading/multiprocessing.